# How to define/design a custom partitions for spark app which using cassandra-connector

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, datastax

I am using spark-cassandra-connector.Need to fetch data from oracle table.
I have "fiscal_year" and "date_of_creation" columns.
currently i have set

```
.option("lowerBound", 2000);
.option("upperBound",2020);
.option("partitionColumn", "fiscal_year");
```

//this works but it resulting  lot of skewness in data. as a result spark working running for hours.

Hence would like to use  "date_of_creation" column as partitioning key as below

```
.option("lowerBound", "31-MAR-02");
.option("upperBound", "01-MAY-19");
.option("partitionColumn", "date_of_creation");
```

But it gives an error like "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER"

what is wrong here?
Is there any possibility set multiple columns as  like

```
option("partitionColumn", ["date_of_creation" ,"fiscal_year"]);
```

for some records in the oracle table if ,"fiscal_year" is null , how to write a Custom Partitioner in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Upper and Lower Bound must be numeric and the corresponding partitioning column. It's that simple, not DATE Type or String equivalent. You can have numeric equivalents of dates, of course.

See an excellent post, not me: https://medium.com/@radek.strnad/tips-for-using-jdbc-in-apache-spark-sql-396ea7b2e3d3

Comment: thank you , a quick question ... here in this sample  .option("numPartitions", 10)
  .option("partitionColumn", "owner_id")          does it mean each owner_id records divided into 10 partitions ?

Comment: Spark will generate queries to db. N ranges

Comment: now it supports Date it seems , https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22814    But when i tried it is giving java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
       As Date being treated as Timestamp , not sure how to specify what is passing is Date rather than TimeStamp

Comment: 2.4 you mean? Mmm. Would make sense though

Comment: but it is giving error ...https://gist.github.com/shatestest/34c6f7fda3e24499080b6d03e2bbb45d